# Spring Framework.Creating Jobs(Which can be started , paused, Resumed(From where it was paused))

Tags: spring, jobs

I have a scenario where I have to make an HTTP request using JOB.
The job will make an HTTP request for different job parameters.
There can be multiple jobs of same type but would have different job parameters.
**Also I want to the details of Started Jobs , Completed Jobs , Paused Jobs on UI in Tabular format where i can see Job report**

Which spring Module can i use for this?

1.**Spring Task Executor / Task Scheduler**
Does it have start / pause functionality?
Can i have multiple instances of the job with different job parameters?
Can I have details of previous jobs(Status , start time , End time etc.)?

2.**Spring Batch**
What i understood from spring batch is , it is used for Reading data from database , processing it , writing to some output stream.
In my case , I want read the data from Database and using that data i have to make a HTTP request to some Server(I don't have to write it it any output stream).
Is it possible in Spring batch?if yes , then How?

OR Is there any other way of doing it?

Please help me.
I am new to Spring Batch and Job framework
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Batch, you could write an ItemProcessor or [ItemWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemWriter.html) that makes HTTP requests. Spring Batch doesn't care what the data source or target are. For ItemWriter your just need to write a class that implements ItemWriter. It can do whatever you want it to. You could use Spring's RESTTemplate to make HTTP Requests.

The thing to grok about Batch is that it really likes to deal with things on an item-by-item (or line-by-line) basis.

You could also consider Spring Integration or Apache Camel.

A real simple ItemWriter:

```
public class HttpItemWriter implements ItemWriter {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Override
    public void write(List objects) throws Exception {
        for(Object item : objects) {
            restTemplate.postForObject(...)'
        }
    }
}
```

Config:

```
<job id="job1">
  <step id="step1">
    <tasklet>
      <chunk>
        <reader><b:bean class="SomeReader"/></reader>
        <writer><b:bean class="HttpItemWriter"/></writer>
      </chunk>
    </tasklet>
  </step>
</job>
```

I'm not going to tell you how to do every step, but that should hopefully get you started. Take a look at http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/03/spring-batch-tutorial.html

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can share any  Example.I have not worked on Batch.I am not able to find any solution(Which has Overridden ItemProcessor or ItemWriter)